# Additional Line Spacing Issue on Custom Font

Tags: android

I use a custom font / custom Typeface for a TextView on my app. The TextView displays a paragraph of a text, but with the additional line spacing from the font itself it's rather irritating. So there's like a quite gap between one line with another on the paragraph. Can anybody know how to reduce the spacing through XML or programmatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`lineSpacingMultiplier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier) attribute of your TextView to reduce/increase the spacing. Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.6"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: This worked great to reduce the padding around a custom font... android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.7"

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the spacing may truncate characters with long decent that are on the last line of text. One alternative it so tweak the custom font parameters. FontForge is a great free font tool and its manual contains a very good introduction to fonts http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/overview.html